# Getting error String Index out of range: 1 but don't know what the issue is

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

```
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * (add a summary comment)
 * @author Samuel Church
 * @author Max Hubenko
 */
public class TicTacToe {

    /**
     * Prints to the console the contents of the given tic-tac-toe grid
     * @param grid 2D char array representing current state of tic-tac-toe game
     */
    public static void printGrid(char[][] grid) {
        System.out.print(grid);
    }

    /**
     * Updates the tic-tac-toe grid given a move by a player (specified by row, column and mark).
     * @param grid current tic-tac-toe grid that will be updated
     * @param row The row the player would like to play in (in the range [0, 2])
     * @param column The column the player would like to play in (in the range [0, 2])
     * @param mark The mark the player would like to place ('X', 'O')
     */
    public static void placeMark(char[][] grid, int row, int column, char mark) {
        grid[row][column] = mark;
    }

    /**
     * Reads user input and stores it in a 3x3 char array. This represents
     * the current state of the tic-tac-toe grid. Expect user input to be
     * three lines with three characters on each line.
     * @param input Scanner instance used to read user input
     * @return tic-tac-toe grid as a 2D char array
     */
    public static char[][] readInGrid(Scanner input){
        char ticTacToeBoard[][] = new char[3][3];
        for (int i = 0; i < ticTacToeBoard.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < ticTacToeBoard[i].length; j++) {
                ticTacToeBoard[i][j] = input.next().charAt(j);
            }
        }
        return ticTacToeBoard;
    }

    /**
     * Create and show a tic-tac-toe board using the methods you'll write.
     * Read user input to determine updates to the board.
     * @param args unused
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // DO NOT EDIT MAIN
        
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Reads in the current state of the tic-tac-toe grid from the user
        char[][] gameGrid = readInGrid(input);
        
        // Reads in the next player's move
        int row = input.nextInt();
        int column = input.nextInt();
        char mark = input.next().charAt(0);

        // Update the tic-tac-toe grid given the next player's move
        placeMark(gameGrid, row, column, mark);

        // Print the updated tic-tac-toe grid
        printGrid(gameGrid);
    }
}
```

When this is input

```
-X-
-X-
-O-
0 2 X
```

This error is given

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 1
    at java.base/java.lang.StringLatin1.charAt(StringLatin1.java:47)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:693)
    at TicTacToe.readInGrid(TicTacToe.java:59)
    at TicTacToe.main(TicTacToe.java:76)
```

Expected it to update the grid with the given character at the correct position but get an error.
When looking it at through a debugger, I can see that the first row of the array is scanned in correctly.
The first row of the array would be -X- but the issue starts as the second row would be 0 then it gives the error afterwards. It should fill the array with the first 3 lines of the input on their corresponding rows.

Comment: `ticTacToeBoard[i][j] = input.next().charAt(j)` - Please carefully read the Javadoc for `Scanner#next()` with regards to how it splits the input into tokens.  Then step through your program in your IDE debugger to see what's actually happening.

Comment: @JimGarrison looking through debugger it shows that the first line of the input is taken in correctly but then for the second row of the array it takes the 0 value of the input skipping the actual grid. Then the error happens

Comment: How many characters do you expect `next()` to read? What is it _actually_ reading?

Comment: @Jim Garrison I am expecting it to read 9 characters in total but I don't know what it is reading

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the scanner.next() as it would take the entire line then move on to the next within the loop which would skip over all the characters I needed.

```java
    for (int i = 0; i < gameGrid.length; i++) {
            String line = input.next();
            for (int j = 0; j < gameGrid[i].length; j++) {
                gameGrid[i][j] = line.charAt(j);
```

By storing the line then looping through that stored line using charAt it takes each char correctly.